# c++ Deleting a derived object via a pointer to its base class

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

in this situation:

```
class a1 {
   public:
     virtual ~a1(){}  
     int i;
};

class a2 : public a1 {
   public:
     int i2;
};
int main() {
   a1* aa2 = new a2; 
   delete aa2;
}
```

if I delete aa2 then all memory alocated on a2 will be free??
These classes don't have any dynamic allocated data inside.

Comment: Yes, it will be deleted completely. And if you have any dynamically allocated memory within the class you must delete that as well.

Comment: Surely this is covered in whatever resource you are using to learn C++.

Answer (score 0):

Yes all memory will be free due to the virtual destructor. The destructor of a2 will call the destructor of a1.

The first will be called the destructor of a2 because the table of virtual functions will contain its address because an object of type a2 was allocated.

More correctly the delete operator at first will call the destructor of a2 and then it call the delete function that will free the memory.

Comment: The destructor doesn't free memory, though. I believe the OP's concern is resolved by a separate piece of C++ magic.

Comment: @Kerrek SB You are right. It is the delete function that will free the memory.:)

Comment: Right, and the magic is finding the correct pointer to pass to the deallocation function. It's the effect of `dynamic_cast<void>(p)`, but usually optimized.

Comment: It is searched according to the class of the called destructor.

Comment: so if sizeof(a2) is 20 then all 20 bytes will be free, right?